# how to put a php array in an email message?

Tags: php, html, arrays, email

I have a general question about sending an email trough php. How do you put php arrays in the message part of the mail?

below you can see a simple array that i made and tried to put it in the email but this is totally wrong cause I didnt find it on the internet how to do it (I am a beginner. I just started coding with php).

The array:

```
    <?php
    $Array[1] = array('qualitypoint', 'technologies', 'India','Hey');
    $Array[2] = array('quality', 'tech', 'Ind','He');
    $Array[3] = array('q', 't', 'I','H');
   ?>
```

The mailer:

```
<?php
    include "index.php";
    while($row = $LevAdres->fetch_assoc()) {
        $email=null;
         $email= $row['Email'];
    }

    $to = example@hotmail.com;


    $subject = "Bestelling";


    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
    $headers .= "From: Restaurant@test.be" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: people@info.be". "\r\n";
    $headers .= "CC: Restaurant@test.be\r\n";        

    $message = "<?php

    echo '<table>';
    echo '<table>';
    for($i=0;$i<=3;$i++)
    {
        echo "<tr>";
        for($j=1;$j<=3;$j++)
        {    
         echo "<td>{$Array[$j][$i]}<td>";
        }
        echo "</tr>";    
    }
    echo '</table>';
    ?>";


    if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
    echo '<p>successfully sent.</p>';
    } else {
    echo'<p>delivery failed...</p>';
    }


    ?>
```

[This is how the table must look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PDxGx.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go ... complete code

```
        $Array[1] = array('qualitypoint', 'technologies', 'India', 'Hey');
        $Array[2] = array('quality', 'tech', 'Ind', 'He');
        $Array[3] = array('q', 't', 'I', 'H');

        $to = "example@hotmail.com";

        $subject = "Bestelling";

        $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
        $headers .= "From: Restaurant@test.be" . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "Reply-To: your@email.com" . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "CC: Restaurant@test.be\r\n";

        $message = "";
        $message .= '<table>';
        for ($i = 0; $i <= 3; $i++) {
            $message .= "<tr>";
            for ($j = 1; $j <= 3; $j++) {
                $message .= "<td>{$Array[$j][$i]}</td>";
            }
            $message .= "</tr>";
        }
        $message .= '</table>';


        if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
            echo '<p>successfully sent.</p>';
        } else {
            echo'<p>delivery failed...</p>';
        }
```

Comment: please change email add to your email address please. you keep sending me email !!! @Sander Herreman

Answer (score 0):

Change your $message variable to this.

```
$message = "<table>";
for($i=0;$i<=3;$i++)
    {
        $message .= "<tr>";
        for($j=1;$j<=3;$j++)
        {    
         $message .= "<td>{$Array[$j][$i]}<td>";
        }
        $message .= "</tr>";    
    }
    $message .= '</table>';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to put it into message then don't echo it but write it in message body

change your echo code to

```
$array = [
     ['qualitypoint', 'technologies', 'q'],
     ['technologies', 'tech', 't'],
     ['India', 'ind', 'i'],
];

$message = "";
$message .= '<table>';
foreach ($array as $row)
{
    $message .= "<tr>";
    foreach ($row as $cell)
    {    
         $message .= "<td>$cell</td>";
    }
    $message .= "</tr>";    
}
$message .= '</table>';
```

However if you want to echo it then you can catch output buffering and use it contents but I don't recommend it. Using foreach makes it more readable as well. Also consider naming your variables with lower camel case.

Answer (score 0):

I can see that you have a doublequotes issue. Try putting it this way:
`echo '<td>'."{$Array[$j][$i]}".'<td>'`;